# Android retrieving result on onActivityResult from another activity using bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hello everyone if you would kindly help me. I'm stuck on how to retrieve the bundle data from another activity. Basically I have two activities which is that when I pressed a button on the first activity, it will go on the second activity and then sets the string values which is later on to be passed on the first activity. What I did was I used the bundle to put the string values. My question is that how can I get the bundle values (of strings) from the second activity and return it on to the first activity? Here is my code:

**FirstActivity (going on to second activity):**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,
                        SecondActivity.class), REQUEST_CODE_SAMPLE);
            }
        });
```

**SecondActivity: (returning the bundle value)**

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("A", "Aloha");
                        bundle.putString("B", "Bubbles");

            setResult(
                    Activity.RESULT_OK,
                    getIntent().putExtras(b));
                    }
                });
}
```

**FirstActivity (going to retrieve the bundle values):**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_SAMPLE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                //WHAT TO DO TO GET THE BUNDLE VALUES//
                String a = //STORE FIRST VALUE OF BUNDLE
                String b = //STORE SECOND VALUE OF BUNDLE
        }

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch (requestCode) {
  case REQUEST_CODE_SAMPLE:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            //WHAT TO DO TO GET THE BUNDLE VALUES//
            String a = bundle.getString("A");
            String b = bundle.getString("B");
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

but take care, you must use the intent passed to the `onActivityResult` not `getIntent`

Also in **SecondActivity**, you need to use a new intent:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("A", "Aloha");
                    bundle.putString("B", "Bubbles");

                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    returnIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I was using getIntent which is wrong geeez. Thank you my problem is solved. :)