# How can I use Intent to access a method from another activity?

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio and have a method in my MapsActivity that I need to access from another activity. I think using intent is the best way, but I do not know how to.

Comment: "I am using Android Studio and have a method in my MapsActivity that I need to access from another activity" -- that is not a good idea, and it is not directly possible. Perhaps these should not be two separate activities, but instead should be a single activity. Or, perhaps this method belongs on some other class, that both activities can access.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bad idea. The activity which you would like to invoke the method could be stopped while you are on the second activity, for example.
If you need the method, instantiate the class. If the method is refreshing some view on it's activity, you could maybe use "onActivityResult". Otherwise you could create an abstract class and call the method.

Comment: well this is what i need to do... I have a second activity that has a button to take you back to the map, wait for the user to click a specific marker (get the latitude and longitude), and then go back to the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using `onActivityResult`.

When you go back to the first Activity you would call `startActivityForResult`. Then you put the data in a new intent when the user clicks the marker and finish similar to:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

and then handle the result in your second activity.

More details are here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/4888701

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Based on your comment, and as *Felipe Martins* pointed out,`startActivityForResult()` can work for you.
Use `bundle.putDouble` to add `lattitude` and `longitude` to the bundle and retrieve it later in  `onActivityResult()`.

Use this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25642483/4941959